# Android: Auto Install apk on our rom/device

Tags: android, installation, rom

We started to work on special-purpose android project

Question 1:
Please assume that we have our android rom, we deliver devices with this rom
so we have app which names as *"ApplicationManager"* on this rom as bundled/pre-installed application and also ApplicationManager have all permissions

is it possible that this ApplicationManager app can install other application without installation confirm or uninstall any our installed applications? *(our application are signed with same certificate, so developer is seen same)*

Question 2:
Is is possible when ApplicationManager is not pre-installed *[we could not succeed this scenario]*

Question 3:
What is known source for Android and how can we be a known source on Android?

Thanks.

Comment: this sounds like somethig that should be asked on the android-porting mailing list... but if you have root-capable apk you should be able to pull off question #1. also that's what the vendor folder is for ;)

Answer (score 0):

If you have your own rom/device then you should **NOT** be doing it with the ApplicationManager, but you **SHOULD** be modifying the Build's makefiles.